# Is it possible to catch Twilio webhook error to log them in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm working on a project with Twilio and NodeJS.
I set up a `twilio.webhook()` and as a requirement, I need to catch when there is an error and log that.

For example, if the webhook fails with `403 Forbidden` I should be able to catch it and log an error in the console about it.

I cannot find a way online and I read Twilio docs here
[Twilio doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-express-app-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests)

I made a validation utility to be able to validate Twilio in several places but cannot log which would be important

```
const validate = (req, res, next) => {
  log.info('Twilio Access Validation');

    const { NODE_ENV } = process.env;
    const { authToken } = config.get('twilio');

    const shouldValidate = NODE_ENV !== 'development';

    const validateTwilio = twilio.webhook({ validate: true }, 'authToken');

    router.use(validateTwilio);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't hook into the validation failure with the `webhook` function, but you could write your own middleware function that takes inspiration from the [`webhook` function](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/lib/webhooks/webhooks.js#L232-L288).

Something like this might work:

```js
const { validateExpressRequest } = require("twilio");

function webhook() {
  var opts = {
    validate: true,
  };

  // Process arguments
  var tokenString;
  for (var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i];
    if (typeof arg === 'string') {
      tokenString = arg;
    } else {
      opts = _.extend(opts, arg);
    }
  }

  // set auth token from input or environment variable
  opts.authToken = tokenString ? tokenString : process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

  // Create middleware function
  return function hook(request, response, next) {
    // Do validation if requested
    if (opts.validate) {
      // Check if the 'X-Twilio-Signature' header exists or not
      if (!request.header('X-Twilio-Signature')) {
        
        // Log error here

        return response.type('text/plain')
          .status(400)
          .send('No signature header error - X-Twilio-Signature header does not exist, maybe this request is not coming from Twilio.');
      }
      // Check for a valid auth token
      if (!opts.authToken) {

        // Log error here

        console.error('[Twilio]: Error - Twilio auth token is required for webhook request validation.');
        response.type('text/plain')
          .status(500)
          .send('Webhook Error - we attempted to validate this request without first configuring our auth token.');
      } else {
        // Check that the request originated from Twilio
        var valid = validateExpressRequest(request, opts.authToken, {
          url: opts.url,
          host: opts.host,
          protocol: opts.protocol,
        });

        if (valid) {
          next();
        } else {
 
          // Log error here

          return response
            .type('text/plain')
            .status(403)
            .send('Twilio Request Validation Failed.');
        }
      }
    } else {
      next();
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea though, I might propose a pull request to the library that allows you to pass a function to the `webhook` function via the options that gets called when the webhook fails for some reason.

Comment: Cool that nice. So instead to use the twilio webhook directly will use similar to the one you shared it here. That nice and I can then log the things as I need.

Comment: Exactly. That is actually the code from the `webhook` function in the Twilio library, you could write your own similar one, which could be simpler (that handles a bunch of different ways to use it) but as long as you call `validateExpressRequest` and handle the result, you can log errors or pass the request on.

Comment: Perfect I'll be giving a try but really nice 

Comment: I'm having an issue here var valid = validateExpressRequest(request, opts.authToken, {
          url: opts.url,
          host: opts.host,
          protocol: opts.protocol,
        });
Is always forbidden and have no clue why. Do I have to call the hook inside every single route endpoint? I did like router.use(webhook()) is that ok?

Comment: You only need to run that middleware on endpoints that are called by Twilio. Do not add the middleware for your entire application. If your Twilio webhook endpoint is `router.post("/messages", (req, res) => {`, for example, then do `router.post("/messages", webhook(), (req, res) => {`.